# CSS Scroll stoping and repeat issue

Tags: css

I cannot get the text to align or scroll properly, for some reason it wants to stop mid scroll and it jumps on the last one.

https://jsfiddle.net/s7hw8zzk/

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="visible">
    <ul>
      <li>Welcome</li>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Family</li>
      <li>Friends</li>
      <li>Welcome</li>     
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `line-height` is 50px , your keyframe animation should be based on a multiple of 50px instead of 40px.

```
@keyframes change {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  23% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  33% {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
    46% {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }

  56% {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
  66% {
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
  90% {
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: -150px;
  } 
}
```

Comment: it still jumps at the last line, and the font is pushed down in the brackets